# Backbone fetch (or sync) doesn't look up right url

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization, fetch

I'm trying to get some data from the node server, which works fine, but when I try to GET data via the Backbone fetch (or sync), the request fails. I noticed that, for some reason, actual request is wrong: 'GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/' where it should be 'GET http://localhost:3000/cars', since '/cars' is the value of the URL field that Backbone uses by convention for these operations. These are the relevant modules:

```
var Backbone = require("backbone");
var Car = require('models/car');
var Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Car,
url: '/cars',
// Unselect all Car Cards
resetSelected: function() {
    for (var i=1; i<=this.length; ++i) {
        var carcard=this.get(i);
        carcard.set({"selected": false});
        console.log(carcard.attributes.name + ' unselected');
    }
},
// Select a specific model from the collection
selectByID: function(id) {
    this.resetSelected();
    var carcard = this.get(id);
    carcard.set({"selected": true});
    console.log(carcard.attributes.name + " selected");
    return carcard.attributes.id;
}
});
module.exports = Cars;
```

And a model:

```
var Backbone = require("backbone");
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    year: 2011,
    brand: "Brand",
    model: "Model",
    name: "Car Name",
    pictureFle: "img/car.jpg",
    kmTraveled: 0,
    litresSpent: 0,
    selected: false
},
});
module.exports = Car;
```

I tried to populate the collection like this:

```
var cars = new Cars();
cars.fetch();
```

but, as I explained, failed. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Please post your model and your collection. Additionally, please post any libraries or other code (even your own) which may be dynamically modifying either your collection or your model. As this question stands, it's nearly impossible to answer, and most answers will just be educated guesses. [Here's a short summary of good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note this: "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some."

Comment: Thanks for the update, are you using Browserify (browser target platform) or is this in Node (server target platform)?

Comment: I'm using both, same classes are used on the Node server and on the client (only made available to the browser via webpack, instead of browserify). This listing is from the client.

Comment: Random aside:  `resetSelected()` is broken: to iterate over the collection use `this.each(...)` instead of the `for` loop.  If you do stick to the `for` loop, access each model by `this.at(i)` (which retrieves by index) instead of `this.get(i)` (which retrieves by ID).

Comment: Can you some details on how you're invoking `webpack`?  As *rockerest* notes, the only way I can see the code you've provided giving the wrong URL is by some other library changing your Model/Collection dynamically.

Comment: This command calls webpack: "webpack app/app.js static/js/bundle.js". file app.js contains usual stuff, wires the whole application together. Everything works and then breaks when I try to use Backbone's fetch. As for the loop, thanks for pointing it out - I can't remember now why I didn't use each or map etc.

Comment: @LazyDal Is it possible [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/76) is like yours? Are you using socket.io?

Comment: No, I don't use socket.io. I already gave up the thing and I am using jQuery to fetch the data.

Comment: My guess after everything is that webpack hot-swap server for React, that I tried to use, also issues it's own request to it's server and that it somehow introduced all these complexities. And it didn't even work 'out-of-the-box'. I'll simply remove it and see what happens. If I manage to make it work as it should I'll come here with a write-up.